# Systemd and controlling network settings

Tags: scripting, systemd, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to figure out best way to control network settings in best way possible in real time.

My current plan is this:

- Start `ip -s -d -o monitor` with systemd and write its output to file generated with `mkfifo` or write tiny script which outputs to tcp socket `127.0.0.1:<some port>`
- Write shell script which reads the file/socket and generate systemd network config files on the fly if there are changes and of course use other commands to read additional data for systemd configuration depending of the change

This way you can use `ip <cmd>` command to change network settings in real time and also you can write systemd config files by hand and restarting `networkd` and then again both `ip` and `systemd`'s network settings stays in sync after boot.

Then the question: or is there even better way?

For example is there commands like:

- `systemd-networkd --add-vlan 123 --name lan`
- `systemd-networkd --attach-vlan lan --device interface0`
- `systemd-networkd --monitor --script /etc/network_changes_script.sh`

Comment: Do you want this to be a fully automated / scripted task, or do you want to be able to interactively modify settings using the same interface? It sounds as though you want the latter, which would complicate things. What have you tried so far? You shouldn't see many configuration changes that you didn't in one way or another initiate. If you do, address that in a static manner - not in real time - fix it rather than apply a band aid. You would see things like physical link state changes, wifi stats - for which you may have a use case to take action in response to, but it's not clear to me.